# Optimization issue when creating dynamic HTML element inside loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

I have an array of pre-set words that I want to randomize and map whitespace after each entry, then split into individual characters which are then put into an html element as individual `<div>`. I have this so far which does work but it gets somewhat slow beyond like **150-200** characters which is understandable I guess. I need each character to be in it's own `<div>` so I'm not sure how to optimize this.

I have an algorithm structure similar to the code snippet below. How do I avoid the optimization issue when rendering lots of dynamic HTML elements in the loop?

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
let currentIndex = arr.length;
let current__text = [], count, randomIndex;

while (currentIndex != 0) {
  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
  --currentIndex;
  [current__text[currentIndex], arr[randomIndex]] = [
    current__text[randomIndex], arr[currentIndex]];
}
  
arr = arr.slice(0, count).map(e => e + ' ').join('').split('');

arr.pop();

for (item of arr) {
  container.innerHTML += `<div class="char">${item}</div>`;
}
```

```css
#container{}

.char{}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Unrelated note: Start using semicoloms. Not using semicolons can easily make your code less readable and even cause errors in some edge cases.

Comment: Could you show an example of expected output?

Comment: @Bulent added expected output

Comment: You don't seem to be modifying `arr` at all - and what is `current__text`?

Comment: my bad @skara9 i copied and pasted it from my code without changing it to make it match what i had already put in, current__text should be arr.

Comment: It's slow because of this: `container.innerHTML += ...`. Don't set `innerHTML` in a loop (it re-creates all the HTML of `container` on every round and forces the layout calculation), instead use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), or rather create the elements dynamically, append them to a `documentFragment`, and then append the `documentFragment` to the DOM. Also, using a styleSheet instead of attaching inline styles might spped up the creation process a bit.

Comment: @Teemu You are a lifesaver. you are right the innerHTML += was the problem... Now it is much faster. Thanks!

Comment: @Teemu I used the `insertAdjacentHTML()` method for the first time. I tried the code example in the answer and found it to be much faster than `innerHTML`. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Sercan Setting `innerHTML` of an element in the DOM can be used only for one purpose, to make an element empty, it should not be used to do anything else. Just read all the recommendations and warnings in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: @vvhitearmor I've updated the post to be executable as I think it's a common issue. I hope that will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the algorithm you developed has no effect on the result. The `printArray()` method in the solution I developed is equivalent to what you are currently doing.

I added the change specified by [@Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu) to the program and compared the results. As [@Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu) pointed out, `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()` method is very fast to `Element.innerHTML` property. Below is a comparison of the runtimes:

```
Duration (insertAdjacentHTML): 2.7000000029802322 milliseconds
Duration (innerHTML):          85.70000000298023  milliseconds
```

*NOTE:* To compare the runtime differences of the `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()` method and the `Element.innerHTML` property, I assign none to the `display` property of the `.char` class style, so an element is not printed on the screen.

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let firstArray = [], secondArray = [];

function measurePerformance(method, mode, array){
  var startTime = performance.now();
  method(mode, array);
  var endTime = performance.now();
  console.log(`Duration (${mode}): ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds`);
}

function generateArray(firstArray, secondArray){
  for(let i = 100 ; i > 50 ; --i){
    firstArray.push(i);
    secondArray.push(i);
  }
}

function printArray(mode, array){
  array = array.map(e => e + ' ').join('').split('');
  
  if(mode === "insertAdjacentHTML"){
    for(item of array){
      container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<div class="char">${item}</div>`);
    }
  }
  else if(mode === "innerHTML"){
    for(item of array){
      container.innerHTML += `<div class="char">${item}</div>`;
    }
  }
}

generateArray(firstArray, secondArray);
measurePerformance(printArray, "insertAdjacentHTML", firstArray);
measurePerformance(printArray, "innerHTML", secondArray);
```

```css
.char{
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I've put a bit more [challenge to the test](https://jsfiddle.net/rqez2n71/1/) by using a larger array. It's notable, that the rendering is still running when the console says the task is done (only the JS part is done). `documentFragment` seems to be approximately twice as fast as `insertAdjacentHTML`. If we'd render a large table element, I'd believe the gap would be much bigger.

Comment: Thank you @Teemu that has made it even faster.

Comment: @vvhitearmor Yep, often more code is more efficient in speed-wise.

Answer (score 0):

To create the letters you need this:

```js
arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

const output = arr.map(
    (word) => word.trim().split('')
);

console.log(output)
```

I didn't add HTML part to my answer. If you need help about it, let me know.